# How to erase specific row from QListWidget

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qstring, qlistwidget

I have a small `ui` with 1 `QListWidget`. In this `ui`there is a predefined row in the `QListWidget` called "Add New".

I drag and drop several files from a folder into a `QListWidget`. So there are all my files plus the "Add New" record.

The "Add Record" is used as a doubleClick to create a New File and store it both in the `QListWidget` and in the local folder of the computer.

**The problem** is that when I erase a specific record from the `QListWidget`, several files are erased together and I don't know why.

See below the steps:

1. I launch the application:

[image]

2. I drag and drop some files and I right click on the last one to erase it:

[image]

3. **As soon as I erase that, several other are also erased** as shown below:

[image]

Below is the logic I used:

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QAction *remove;
    remove = new QAction(QIcon(":/icons/remove_item.png"), "Remove", this);
    QObject::connect(remove, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_eraseBtn_clicked()));
    ui->listWidget->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu);
    ui->listWidget->addAction(remove);
    setAcceptDrops(true);

     ui->listWidget->addItem("Add New");
     ui->listWidget->item(0)->setSelected(true);
}


void MainWindow::on_eraseBtn_clicked()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ui->listWidget->count(); ++i)
    {
        QString str = ui->listWidget->item(i)->text();
        if (str != "Add New")
            delete ui->listWidget->item(i);
        qDebug() << ui->listWidget->item(i) << str;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

As proposed by @absolute.madeness, a `while`loop could be used too. Not exactly the behavior but close. With the following loop, all the records (or row) of the `QListwidget` are erased with the exception of the row "Add New"

```
void MainWindow::on_eraseBtn_clicked()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ui->listWidget->count(); ++i)
    {
        while(i < ui->listWidget->count() && ui->listWidget->item(i)->text() != "Add New")
            delete ui->listWidget->item(i);
    }
}
```

**What I have done so far is:**

1. on the slot **on_eraseBtn_clicked()** I just added the line `delete  ui->listWidget->currentItem();` to see if at least the record was successfully erased. Which it was so I was sure that the slot was properly triggered.
2. After that I did some research and the best approach was to loop through the all `QListWidget` and and as soon as the record with the `QString` `Add New` is found, please keep it and pass to the next record and erase it. This methodology is also described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543952/c-delete-a-custom-widget-from-qlistwidget). But for some reason more then one record is erased.
3. I tried to do additional research and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963717/qt-listwidget-itemclicked-into-a-string)
4. I tried to delete by context as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427601/delete-qlistwidget-item-by-text-content).

Any other pointers you can suggest?

Comment: This effect of leaving half of the items happens because when you delete `item(i)` the next item (previously accessed as `item(i+1)`) will immediately take its place and the number of items aka `count()` will decrease by 1. The inner part of the `for` loop should be something like `while(i < ui->listWidget->count() && ui->listWidget->item(i)->text() != "Add New") delete ui->listWidget->item(i);`. Alternatively, you can collect the items you wish to delete into a `QList<>` using the `for` loop and then delete all items at once by calling `qDeleteAll` on this list outside `for`.

Comment: @absolute.madness, thank you for your comment and reading the question. I tried your suggestion but instead of selectively erasing one item, it erase all the object except "Add New". So ok for keeping "Add New" because the user would want to still create new records. But how I can selectively erase the record?

Comment: @absolute.madness, I added **update** to the question with the solution you proposed. Please let me know if that is what you suggested in the comment. :)

Comment: actually, by reading your code I thought you wanted to delete all items ecxept one because you tried to call `delete` several times in a loop. If you want to delete a single item then call `delete` just once. I cannot see the code where you first search for the item and I don't understand why `delete  ui->listWidget->currentItem();` which you said to work doesn't do what you want. So now I don't understand the question :) if you wish to keep "Add New" then add `if` before deleting the current item. Perhaps you need to loop over the selected items?

Comment: Well obviously you're going to remove more items than one since you're removing items in a for loop. What was wrong with deleting `ui->listWidget->currentItem()`?

Comment: @thuga, hi thanks for reading. Yes, the problem is that if I put `ui->listWidget->currentItem()` in the slot it is going to erase selectively (which is the goal I am trying to achieve). The problem is that "Add New" will also be erased. That is why I thought about looping through the entire `QListWidget` rows and try to avoid that. I am only trying to selectively erase rows. If the user happens to erase all the rows it can not erase "Add New".

Comment: I thought that the initial loop I wrote was straightforward, but I obtained the strange effect of erasing multiple rows with one click. I tried different variations of the loop but I could not figure out what is happening and that is why I wanted to drop a question to SO.

Comment: What does [`ui->listWidget->selectedItems()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#selectedItems) return?

Comment: @thuga, it returns the path of the row `/home/to/folder/example_1.txt`

Comment: @EsoMars how about `for(auto item: ui->listWidget->selectedItems()) if(item->text() != "Add New") delete item;`?

Comment: @absolute.madness, thanks it is working as expected! the user can selectively erase rows but not "Add New". I appreciate it!

Comment: @absolute.madness, perfect I posted the solution to the question. Thank you for your time in helping out! :)

Answer (score 1):

I originally wrote a for loop that was straightforward but I incurred in the problem to `delete item(i)` recursively. The next item previously accessed as `item(i+1)` will decrease by 1, creating a strange effect of erasing several rows unexpectedly.
As proposed by @absolute.madeness, below the solution that avoids that. I hope other will benefit from this solution and don't get stuck wondering why a simple loop can create such unexpected issues:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    remove = new QAction(QIcon(":/icons/remove_item.png"), "Remove", this);
    QObject::connect(remove, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_eraseBtn_clicked()));

// other operations in the constructor....
}


void MainWindow::on_eraseBtn_clicked()
{
    for(auto item: ui->listWidget->selectedItems())
        if(item->text() != "Add New") delete item;
}
```

This way the user selectively erase single rows in the `QListWidget` leaving only a specific row.